# Moment time comparison

Tags: javascript

I want to limit the time between 12:00 AM and 6:00 AM but i'm getting an error "Invalid Date" on line var startTimeGraveyard and var timeGraveyard

```
var startTimeGraveyard = moment("12:00 AM").format('LT');

var timeGraveyard = moment("6:00 AM").format('LT');

if (time >= startTimeGraveyard && time <= timeGraveyard) {
    $('#lblGraveyard').text("Graveyard Schedule");
}
```

Comment: use [moment diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Comment: Whats the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var startTimeGraveyard = moment("12:00 AM", "LT");

var timeGraveyard = moment("6:00 AM", "LT");

if (time.isBetween(startTimeGraveyard, timeGraveyard)) {
    $('#lblGraveyard').text("Graveyard Schedule");
}
```

That's assuming that `time` is a moment object aswell.

This works because `.format(<format>)` is used to generate a string out of a moment object. In order to initialize a moment object from a string, you have to pass the format as a second parameter to the `moment()` function.

`console.log(moment('1:00 PM', 'LT').format('HH:mm:ss'))` will initialize the moment object correctly, but in the end will output 13:00:00 to the console because of the format.